# Access static directory when using Bokeh as a library

Tags: python, bokeh, tornado

I am trying to make a bokeh server that servers the same view to all people connecting. I have been able to achieve this using the Bokeh in [library mode](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html#embedding-bokeh-server-as-a-library) using the following code:

```py
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
from bokeh.server.server import Server
from bokeh.plotting import curdoc

io_loop = IOLoop.current()
server = Server(applications={'/myapp': self.make_document},
                io_loop=io_loop,
                allow_websocket_origin=['{0}.com:5001'.format(
                    hostname.lower()), 'localhost:5001'],
                port=5001,
                )
  
server.start()
server.show('/myapp')
io_loop.start()
```

Run with `python main.py`, but I cannot access the static directory `/myapp/static`.

If I instead do:

```py
self.make_document(curdoc())
```

And start `myapp` using `bokeh server --show myapp` I can access static just fine, but each new browser tab connecting gets a new view.

Is there a way to access static in library mode? Or a way to serve the same view to all connecting and still use [bokeh document mode](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html#directory-format).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found answer in [Bokeh Tornado Embed Example](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/2.2.3/examples/howto/server_embed/tornado_embed.py)

```py
from tornado.web import StaticFileHandler
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
from bokeh.server.server import Server
from bokeh.plotting import curdoc

io_loop = IOLoop.current()
server = Server(applications={'/myapp': self.make_document},
                io_loop=io_loop,
                allow_websocket_origin=['{0}.com:5001'.format(
                    hostname.lower()), 'localhost:5001'],
                port=5001,
                extra_patterns=[
                    (r'/mydir/(.*)', StaticFileHandler, {'path': 
                    os.path.normpath(os.path.dirname(__file__) + '/mydir')})],
                )
  
server.start()
server.show('/myapp')
io_loop.start()
```

Here the `mydir` needs to be in the `myapp` directory and not the parent one.